# respond_to :js is not working gem 'acts_as_votable' rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This code is fine. but
everytime i need to reload page to see like button works. do not know why its not responding.
show.html.erb

```
<span class="like-count"><%= pluralize(@property.cached_votes_up, 'like') %></span>
<%= render 'shared/actions', resource: @property %>
```

shared/_actions.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'likes/form', likeable: resource %>
<% end %>
```

likes/_form.html.erb

```
  <% if current_user.liked? likeable %>
      <%= form_tag unlike_path(likeable_type: likeable.class.to_s, likeable_id: likeable.id), method: :post, remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
          <% button_tag class: 'btn btn-block liked' do %>
              <%= fa_icon 'thumbs-up' %> unlike
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% else %>
      <%= form_tag like_path(likeable_type: likeable.class.to_s, likeable_id: likeable.id), remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
          <% button_tag class: 'btn btn-block' do %>
              <%= fa_icon 'thumbs-up' %> like
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

likes/create.js.erb

```
$("#<%= @likeable_type.downcase %>-<%= @likeable.id %> .like").html("<%=j render('likes/form', likeable: @likeable) %>");
$("#<%= @likeable_type.downcase %>-<%= @likeable.id %> .like-count").html("<%= pluralize(@likeable.cached_votes_up, 'like') %>");
```

likes/destroy.js.erb

```
$("#<%= @likeable_type.downcase %>-<%= @likeable.id %> .like").html("<%=j render('likes/form', likeable: @likeable) %>");
$("#<%= @likeable_type.downcase %>-<%= @likeable.id %> .like-count").html("<%= pluralize(@likeable.cached_votes_up, 'like') %>");
```

likes_controller.rb

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_likeable
  respond_to :js

  def create
    @likeable.liked_by current_user
    @likeable.create_activity(:like, owner: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @likeable.disliked_by current_user
    activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find_by_trackable_id_and_key(@likeable.id, "#{@likeable_type.downcase}.like")
    activity.destroy if activity.present?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private
  def find_likeable
    @likeable_type = params[:likeable_type].classify
    @likeable = @likeable_type.constantize.find(params[:likeable_id])
  end
end
```

likes_helper.rb

```
module LikesHelper
  def find_like(likeable)
    likeable.get_likes.where(user: current_user)
  end
end
```

do not know why its not working.  any idea?

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error and expected behaviour?

Comment: when i click like button its not showing unlike button as expected. I need to reload the page.

Comment: Doesn't the page reload when you click the button?

Comment: no . Its not reloading

Comment: Remove `remove: true` and it will reload.

Comment: i want it as ajax respond.

Comment: Bind the ajax request to a callback and update the view accordingly. Here's more info https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will toggle the like button.

```
<%= form_tag unlike_path(likeable_type: likeable.class.to_s, likeable_id: likeable.id), method: :post, remote: true, data: { type: :json }, class: "unlike #{"hidden" unless current_user.liked?(likeable)}" do %>
    <% button_tag class: 'btn btn-block liked' do %>
        <%= fa_icon 'thumbs-up' %> unlike
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag like_path(likeable_type: likeable.class.to_s, likeable_id: likeable.id), remote: true, data: { type: :json }, class: "unlike #{"hidden" if current_user.liked?(likeable)}" do %>
    <% button_tag class: 'btn btn-block' do %>
        <%= fa_icon 'thumbs-up' %> like
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".unlike").on("ajax:success", function() {
            $(".unlike").addClass("hidden");
            $(".like").removeClass("hidden");
        });

        $(".like").on("ajax:success", function() {
            $(".like").addClass("hidden");
            $(".unlike").removeClass("hidden");
        });
    })
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

You might want to add a loading message using `ajax:beforeSend`.

Comment: i placed your code in my _form.html.erb file and render it .  ajax is not working . I clicked liked button and still need to reload full page to see the effect. ( thanks for your response)

Comment: Any console logs, errors, did the javascript binding work, did it do a request to the server, are the js selectors correct, does it work do toggle the like/dislike buttons? You've to do some debuging by your self, I wont be help you help you with everything as I dont have access to your project.

Comment: when i clicked like button it render files in log , but its not changing my view
`  Rendered likes/_form.html.erb (4.3ms)`
  `Rendered likes/create.js.erb (22.5ms)`
`Completed 200 OK in 705ms (Views: 88.9ms | ActiveRecord: 7.2ms | Solr: 0.0ms)`

Comment: Sorry, but you've to answer my questions and more importantly start debuging your self. Until then I can't help you. And btw, you dont have to explain what the script is suppose to do, that's already stated in your question.